# Randomly not working sound card on Lenovo IdeaPad-3-15IIL05 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, 20.04, soundcard

I have an issue with Ubuntu 20.04 on my new pc (Lenovo IdeaPad-3-15IIL05) I run in dual boot with windows. It randomly (I mean, not every time I reboot) has issues with the sound. I get only "Dummy output" on sound settings and the volume is not tunable or it is totally missing. The times it works, it is still not fully tunable through F2 and F3, but only from the settings. I thought it could be a problem related to the kernel modules, but the output

```
user@IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:/$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
```

seems showing that the right modules are installed. I also used the `alsa-info` script and I discovered something I think can be related to my issues, but my computer skills are not good enough to actually understand how to fix them. I post a sample of the output

```
!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.138211] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.138211] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.138211] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    6.817448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlan0
[    6.876074] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    6.886115] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.887385] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    6.931611] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    6.931612] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.931613] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.931614] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    6.931614] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    6.931615] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    6.931692] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    6.954102] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    6.954180] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[    6.954266] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[    6.954339] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[    6.954424] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[    6.954513] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
[    6.954593] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
[    6.954676] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
[    6.954803] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
[    7.239784] audit: type=1400 audit(1602660318.007:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=668 comm="apparmor_parser"
--
[   14.847444] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   16.861949] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x202f8100
[   17.865989] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x202f8100
[   18.874039] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x202f8100
[   19.882032] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x202f8100
[   20.894028] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[   21.901981] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[   22.905854] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20470500
[   22.931534] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
--
[   23.115276] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   23.913834] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20570500
[   24.619301] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   24.921941] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20670500
[   25.925884] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20770500
[   26.938021] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20870500
[   27.946007] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20970500
[   28.954007] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20a70500
```

and so on with the last lines repeated a bunch of times. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this problem, it seems related to the buggy pulseaudio version I have installed. Instead of rebooting I can type on terminal `killall pulseaudio` and then `pulseaudio &` to restart it in background. This seems to correct the issue. I've also noticed that just `killall -9 pulseaudio` without restarting pulseaudio manually seems to fix the problem even quicker, which is odd, but it works. If anyone has suggestions about the nature of this behavior, feel free to add a comment.